# Where would we insert the commas in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Consider the sentence:

Many people find the best times for meditation are in the **morning** when they first wake **up** or at **night** just before bed.

1. Commas after bolded words?
2. Change "times" to "time" and "are" to "is" to correspond to conjunction "or"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Commas after the bolded words are optional. The sentence can work with or without the commas, even though commas will feel more aesthetic.
2. Yes, *time* would sounds better than *times*.
    `Many people find the best` **time** `for meditation is.......`

Answer (score 0):

Optional comma after the word up only:

> Many people find the best times for meditation are in the morning when they first wake up, or at night just before bed.

The word time should be singular and the verb should be singular as both elements, morning or night, are singular.

Singular:

> Many people find the best time for meditation is in the morning when they first wake up, or at night just before bed.

Plural:

> Many people find the best times for meditations are mornings when they first wake up or nights just before bed.